# Nucleo64 Vdd maximum output current

Tags: stm32, esp8266, nucleo, esp01

I'm trying to power an ESP-01 (8266 chip) using the 3.3v pin of a nucleo 64 stm32F446re board, but the module won't power up (red LED off). I've searched the web for information on the maximum current my board can put out, but haven't found anything useful. The documentation also doesn't specify a value. The chip requires an average current of 80mA. Can anyone help me figure out if it's a power issue?

Comment: Well, have you figured out what component makes the 3.3V and how much it can output, minus what the onboard components consume?

Comment: esp32  may require 3A when transmiting :)

Comment: Measure voltage on both nucleo and ESP8266. What is the difference? Check pinout again. Nucleo voltage regulators are powerfull enough for ESP8266 and many more. If it does not work at all I think there is other issue than voltage regulator capability.